# NineOldAndroids: set view pivot

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm using the wonderful framework NineOldAndroids, but I can't find anything to set the pivot on my animated views. Specifically, I'm trying to do a `scaleX` + `scaleY` animation with a pivot on the top-left edge, so `pivotX` = 0 and `pivotY` = 0. On Honeycomb and beyond I would just set `myView.setPivotX(0)` and `myView.setPivotY(0)`, but how to do it for pre-Honeycomb devices with NineOldAndroids? I tried the following:

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.playTogether(
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "pivotX", -(myView.getWidth() / 2), -(myView.getWidth() / 2)),
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "pivotY", -(myView.getHeight() / 2), -(myView.getHeight() / 2)),
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "scaleX", 0, 1),
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "scaleY", 0, 1),
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "alpha", 0, 1)
);
set.setDuration(1000).start();
```

but it doesn't work, the pivot stays at the center of the view.

Can you help me please?

Thanks ;)

Comment: I do not think that NineOldAndroids supports this :-( On Honeycomb or greater (API 11) you can call setPivotY(0) but this method is not available in View of < API 11. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah I know. I examined the source code of NineOldAndroids and I found some references to a pivot for the pre-Honeycomb implementation but I had no luck with my attempts in setting it... :(

Answer (score 18):

Thanks to the author Jake Wharton, here is the solution:

```
AnimatorProxy.wrap(myView).setPivotX(0);
```

at any time, even *after* having called `ObjectAnimator.start()`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know this could be done. That is very useful because without it many animations could not be completed on older devices.

Comment: +1 for giving the author some cred. You might even go the extra mile and link his name to his site. Backlinks are tasty SEO.

Comment: Well, for me it worked ONLY AFTER calling `start()`. Maybe because I used AnimatorSet

Comment: how to set pivot on left side ? so if its scaling it wont change position

Answer (score 15):

AnimatorProxy.wrap(...) didn't have any effect in my case.
However, the following line did the trick:

```
ViewHelper.setPivotY(myView, 0)
```

Comment: AnimatorProxy.wrap did not work for me as well , I am using AnimatorSet . Thumbs up for this answer coz it finally helped me out