# setPivotX doesn't work on android 4.1.1 NineOldAndroids

Tags: android, android-animation, nineoldandroids

I am animating an `ImageView` using `scaleX()`. This is supposed to be a progress bar which fills from left to right. It works without a problem on API 10, 18 and 19. But on API 16 there seems to be a problem with the `setPivotX()` method. I have tried every option in [NineOldAndroids: set view pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496074/nineoldandroids-set-view-pivot) .

```
final ImageView progressBarFill = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.progressbarImageFill);
//...

ViewHelper.setPivotX(progressBarFill, 0);
AnimatorProxy.wrap(progressBarFill).setPivotX(0);
animate(progressBarFill).setDuration(1000).scaleX(0.25f);
```

and

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.playTogether(
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(progressBarFill, "scaleX", 0f, 0.25f)
);
AnimatorProxy.wrap(progressBarFill).setPivotX(0.0f);
ViewHelper.setPivotX(progressBarFill, 0f);
set.setDuration(1000).start();
```

The animation works but it animates from the center of the `ImageView`. Can anyone confirm this issue?

**UPDATE**

I have tried to use androids standard animation package as well:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    progressBarFill.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    progressBarFill.setPivotX(0);
    progressBarFill.setPivotY(0);
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.playTogether(
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(progressBarFill, "scaleX", 0f, 0.25f)
    );
    set.setDuration(2000).start();
}
```

But is still doesnt work on android API 16. So the problem is not only related to the NineOldAndroids library but the standard animation function as well.

Answer (score 3):

Turnes out that setting the pivot X to 0 doesnt go down very well in API 16. So to set the pivot to the very left in the view `progressBarFill.setPivotX(1);`worked a lot better.